# почему результат вложенной горутины не выводится и как это исправить?

Tags: golang

Бьюсь за понимание горутин и каналов. Тема для меня оказалась сложной и один момент не дает мне покоя(так как я его не понимаю).
Я приведу полный код, так как не уверен, что проблема в функции  somework(хотя почти наверняка в ней).

Данная задача является полностью выдуманной чтобы разобраться:

Как мне продолжать выполнение всех горутин, в т.ч main, когда одна из вложенных горутин выполняет длительную операцию...

Все свои мысли я написал в комментах к коду, в т.ч пометил место, которое у меня вызвает вопрос.
Поэтому welcome сразу в код. Спасибо за ваше внимание и время.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    start := time.Now().UnixNano()
    in, out, wait := make(chan int), make(chan int), make(chan bool)
    go somework(in, out, wait, 12)
    // записываем рандомные данные в канал который потом
    // передадим в качестве аргумена в somework
    in <- int(time.Now().Unix())
    // выводим результат работы somework
    fmt.Printf("somework вернула в канале значение: %v\n", <-out)
    end := time.Now().UnixNano()
    fmt.Printf("функция main завершилась через >>%v<< наносекунд после своего начала, выполнив все второстепенные горутины\n", end-start)
    // ждем, пока somework просигнализирует об окончании своей работы.
    <-wait
}

// некая функция, которая внутри себя должна отправить на выполнение длительную операцию.
// все горутины, включая main должны продолжать свое выполнение и когда завершится длительная
// операция вывести результат этой длительной операции независмо от того что в этот момент
// будет делать функция main
func somework(ch, out chan int, wait chan bool, i int) chan int {
    start := time.Now().UnixNano()
    go func() {
        rsultOfrollingAction := make(chan int)
        // далее запускаю длительную операцию чтения файла в отдельной горутине
        go func(rsultOfrollingAction chan int) {
            d := make(chan bool) //для сигнализации об окончании длительного действия
            // начало длительной операции в отдельной горутине
            // результат данной работы, при имеющемся коде, не выводится.
            // ДАННЫЙ ВОПРОС ОТНОСТИИТСЯ КАК РАЗ К ЭТОЙ ПРОБЛЕМЕ
            go func(d chan bool) {
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
                text := readf("text.txt")
                rsultOfrollingAction <- len(text)
                // сигнализируем горутине которая должна вывести количество
                // прочитанных строк, что длительная операция завершене
                d <- true
            }(d)
            // когда d получает сигнал об окончании длительной операции
            <-d
            // выводим результат длительной операции.
            fmt.Printf("вложенная в somework горутина завершила выполенение прочитав из файла %v символов\n", <-rsultOfrollingAction)
        }(rsultOfrollingAction)
        // читаем канал из входных аргументов somework
        a := <-ch
        // записываем в вызодной кнал
        out <- a
        // сигнализируем об окончании somesomework()
        wait <- true
    }()
    fmt.Printf("прошло >>%v<< наносекунд с момента начала функции work и функция somework завершилась передав управление main\n", time.Now().UnixNano()-start)
    // возвращаем канал с результататом работы somework
    return out
}

// поростейшее чтение файла.
func readf(name string) []byte {
    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(name)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(123)
    }
    return f
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Первая проблема

В канал `wait` вы пишете не в той функции. Смотрите, что у вас происходит:

`main` порождает `somework` и продолжает работу. Затем останавливается, ожидая канал `out`.

`somework` порождает вложенную горутину и завершается.

Стартует первая анонимная горутина, которую рантайм Го обозначает как `main.somework.func1`. Она

1. порождает анонимную горутину `main.somework.func1.1`
2. читает канал `in`, записывает в канал `out` и
3. **ТАДАМ** записывает в канал `wait`

Где-то между 2 и 3 **разблокируется `main`**, читая из канала `out`. Затем `main` снова блокируется, ожидая из канала `wait`. И в тот же момент `main` снова пробуждается, так как горутина `main.somework.func1` записала в `wait`.

`main` печатает сообщение и ЗАВЕРШАЕТСЯ. Есть ненулевая вероятность, что вторая анонимная горутина `main.somework.func1.1` даже не успела стартануть.

Вам нужно перенести `wait <- true` в ту горутину, которая ожидает завершения чтения из файла:

```go
    go func() {
        rsultOfrollingAction := make(chan int)
        // далее запускаю длительную операцию чтения файла в отдельной горутине
        go func(rsultOfrollingAction chan int) {
            d := make(chan bool) //для сигнализации об окончании длительного действия
            // начало длительной операции в отдельной горутине
            // результат данной работы, при имеющемся коде, не выводится.
            // ДАННЫЙ ВОПРОС ОТНОСТИИТСЯ КАК РАЗ К ЭТОЙ ПРОБЛЕМЕ
            go func(d chan bool) {
                time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
                text := readf("sample.bin")
                rsultOfrollingAction <- len(text)
                // сигнализируем горутине которая должна вывести количество
                // прочитанных строк, что длительная операция завершене
                d <- true
            }(d)
            // когда d получает сигнал об окончании длительной операции
            <-d
            // выводим результат длительной операции.
            fmt.Printf("вложенная в somework горутина завершила выполенение прочитав из файла %v символов\n", <-rsultOfrollingAction)
            wait <- true
        }(rsultOfrollingAction)
        // читаем канал из входных аргументов somework
        a := <-in
        // записываем в вызодной кнал
        out <- a
        // сигнализируем об окончании somesomework()
        // wait <- true
    }()
```

Видите? Я перенёс запись в `wait` из первой вложенной горутины во вторую, так как вторая горутина точно дождётся чтения из файла благодаря синхронизации через `d` и `rsultOfrollingAction`. Именно она должна сигнализировать, что длинная операция завершена.

## Вторая проблема

При такой синхронизации образуется дедлок. Причина в том, что инструкция `make(chan T)` создаёт канал нулевой ёмкости. То есть читатель блокируется, если нет писателя, писатель блокируется, если нет читателя. Что и просиходит у вас:

- вторая анонимная функция ждёт канал `d` (`<-d`). Так как в момент ожидания `d` третья горутина ещё не стартовала, то вторая горутина блокируется.
- третья анонимная горутина ждёт, потом читает файл, потом записывает результат в `rsultOfrollingAction` (`rsultOfrollingAction <- len(text)`). И ... **тоже блокируется**! Так как у канала `rsultOfrollingAction` в этот момент ещё нет читателя. Читатель - вторая горутина - заблокирована на ожидании `d`.

Что с этим можно сделать.

### План А.

Выбросить `d`. Появление данных в `rsultOfrollingAction` само собой обозначает, что операция чтения завершена.

Пруф: https://go.dev/play/p/mXxkYgXkyxw

`main` дождается выполнения вложенных горутин.

### План Б

Если канал `d` вам дорог сам по себе, то нужно сделать канал `rsultOfrollingAction` асинхронным: `rsultOfrollingAction := make(chan int, 1)`

Если канал пуст, писатель не будет ждать появления читателя. Записанное значение будет записано в буфер канала, и третья горутина благополучно перейдёт к следующей операции `d <- true`

Пруф: https://go.dev/play/p/4BeRqa2ilJT

Comment: Вариант с выкидыванием d подошел больше всего, так как она(d) родилась в потугах добиться синхронизации..Еще учить и учиться и учиться мне))

Comment: более того, осмыслив еще раз программу, понял, что нет нужны делать внешний go func(){}() в somework? так как somework сам выполняется в отдельной горутине, нет нужды его оборачивать в еще одну. Каналы будут читаться и так, потому что чтение из ch и запись в out будут в горутине somework